# gsutil OAuth2 authorization (example of .boto file is needed)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

I'd like to access Google Cloud Storage from my scripts, and I need to automate authentication. By default, gsutil config asks to open a link and type in generated code, and then it writes OAuth token into .boto file.

Google Cloud also supports creating OAuth 2.0 client IDs in "Credentials" page, but I cannot make sense how to plug those credentials (client_id and client_secret) into my .boto file:

> {"installed":{"client_id":"677005197220-eim3l5of3m16225qr0m9vquocj6mugt4.apps.googleusercontent.com","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"pFghf5URxxxBFVRsQ1elWbbZ","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}

(Please don't try to use it, as I slightly modified the codes)

I plugged them in .boto file in this way:

> [OAuth2]
>
> client_id
>   ="677005197220-eim3l5of3m16225qr0m9vquocj6mugt4.apps.googleusercontent.com"
>   client_secret ="pFghf5URxxxBFVRsQ1elWbbZ" provider_label = Google
>   provider_authorization_uri = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
>   provider_token_uri = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

This is how gsutil is failing:

> # gsutil ls gs://mybucket/
>   You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
>   credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
>   and sign up for an account, and then run the "gsutil config" command
>   to configure gsutil to use these credentials.

If I run gsutil config I can configure credentials and then it works, but I need to use my client ID and client secret.
Can someone please suggest how to make gsutil work with .boto with client_id and client_secret? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can create a .boto file with access key ID and secret access key.

`gsutil config -a`

The above commmand will generate a .boto file that you can then use as a sample that you are after.

Comment: I used that sample, and showed the error message with which gsutil is failing after I plug in the keys